# Cant send a form

Tags: javascript

With this form from html:

```
<form name="testform" onsubmit="return processForm(this)">
Number 1: <input type="text" name="number1"/><br />
Number 2: <input type="text" name="number2"/><br />
Number 3: <input type="text" name="number3"/><br />
Number 4: <input type="text" name="number4"/><br />
Number 5: <input type="text" name="number5"/><br />
Number 6: <input type="text" name="number6"/><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send numbers"/>
</form>
```

And this javascript method:

```
var num1 = 0,
num2 = 0,
num3 = 0,
num4 = 0,
num5 = 0,
num6 = 0;
function processForm(form) {
var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("testform");
var textValues = {};
for(var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {
    if(inputs[x].type != "text") {
        continue;
    }
    textValues[inputs[x].name] = inputs[x].value;
}

num1 = textValues['number1'];
num2 = textValues['number2'];
num3 = textValues['number3'];
num4 = textValues['number4'];
num5 = textValues['number5'];
num6 = textValues['number6'];

document.write(num1);
document.write(num2);
document.write(num3);
document.write(num4);
document.write(num5);
document.write(num6);

return false;
}
```

When pressing send numbers:

1. I dont understand why i get:

   undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined
2. These undefined variables, why are they printed in another tab of the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may NEVER use `document.write` after page has loaded. It will WIPE the page and the scripts on it.

Perhaps you meant

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ft7nsfkn/)

```
var textValues = {}; // here in case you need them elsewhere.
function processForm(form) {
  var output=[];
  for(var x = 0; x < form.elements.length; x++) {
    var field = form.elements[x];
    if(field.type == "text") {
      var val = parseInt(field.value,10);
      if (isNaN(val)) val=0; // set the value to 0 if not a number  
      textValues[field.name] = val;
      output.push(val);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML=output.join(",");
  return false;
}
```

adding some `<div id="out"></div>` to your page

Comment: what shold i use then? divs?

Answer (score 2):

```
var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("testform");
```

Should be

```
var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` expects the `tag name` of the controls to find (`input` in this case), not the `name` of the parent control.

Therefore you need:

```
var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Also, set the content in a `div`:

in the html:

```
<div id="output" />
```

js:

```
var s = "" + num1
      + "<br />" + num2
      + "<br />" + num3
      + "<br />" + num4
      + "<br />" + num5
      ;

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = s;
```

A demonstrating [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tceog7a/1/).